# C# PagedList MVC add #anchor in pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

i want to know if i can make my PagedList add and #anchor after ?Page=1

example: http://localhost:10220/Products/MyUrl/Sku?Page=1#Products

i have it:

```
  @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.Products, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Why i have some content before my products and i don't want my clients roll the page all the time while doing paging

obs: Or can i make my PagedList not refresh the page with ajax? someone has one example?

Comment: Your localhost URL won't work on the interwebz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way it's always using ajax! for performance improvements

Your controller code:

```
   public class MyCutomModel
{

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class HomeController : Controller

  //
  // GET: /Home/
  public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
  {
     List<MyCutomModel> model = new List<MyCutomModel>();

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        model.Add(new MyCutomModel { Id = i, Name = "Name " + i.ToString() });
     }

     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
        return PartialView("_Index", model.ToPagedList(page, 4));
     }

     return View(model.ToPagedList(page, 4));
  }
}
```

Your Index View:

```
@model PagedList<MVCApp.Controllers.MyCutomModel>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@DateTime.Now

@Html.Partial("_Index", Model)
```

Your Index Partial View ( "_Index.cshtml" ):

```
@model PagedList<MVCApp.Controllers.MyCutomModel>
<div id="replaceDiv">
   <table class="table">
      <tbody>
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
           <tr>
               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            </tr>
         }
      </tbody>
   </table>
   @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page,   sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "replaceDiv" }))
</div>
```

Note the end of the PagedListPager , this is the secrect

```
PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "replaceDiv" }))
```

Comment: DONT FORGET TO MAKE SURE THAT THE    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script> IS REFERENCE

Comment: Make sure your are referring <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script> on your page and last case on your webconfig, make sure it's true the key     <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Url.Action("Index", new { page }) + "#Products"
```

There's no way to add a fragment (what you refer to as an "anchor") with the routing helpers because fragments are not part of a route; they only apply client-side. Regardless, the lambda can accept any valid expression, not just a single-method call, and `Url.Action` merely returns a string. As a result, you can just tack your fragment to the end of the string and call it a day.